# Why android BLE sends connection parameter update request automatically?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

1. My BLE device(slave) set to disable 'connection parameter update request' on Link Layer.
2. My own Android application on smartphone sends 2 or 3 times of 'connection parameter update request' to slave device when pairing. I did not use requestConnectionPriority(). Why it sent automatically?
3. On the contrary, when pairing with Bluetooth Setting menu on same smartphone(not my application), it does not send 'connection parameter update request' to slave device.

I want my application to do not send it to slave. Is it possible?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7M4jh.png)

Answer (score 3):

Android usually updates the connection parameters shortly after establishment with decreased connection parameters to speed up GATT service discovery and bonding. When that is finished, it updates back to the initial connection parameters.

The master device controls the link and can hence perform a Connection Update procedure at anytime, and the slave must obey the parameters. (If the slave doesn't like the new parameters, it can disconnect.)

When BLE was introduced with the 4.0 specification, the only available option for the slave to update connection parameters was to use the L2CAP protocol to ask the host to update the parameters, which it could either reject or accept. If the host accepts the parameters, it performs a Connection Update procedure.

In Bluetooth 4.1 a new procedure called Connection Parameters Request procedure was introduced, which can be initiated by both slave and master to negotiate parameters both devices support. However, the master still decides the final parameters to be used and then performs a Connection Update procedure as usual.

So no, you cannot force Android to not perform connection parameter updates, since it's built into the Bluetooth stack and this part can't be controlled by an app.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Emil, it's very helpful.